# Titanium Alloy Views

Tags: ios, titanium, view, titanium-alloy

I am using the Napp Drawer module in order to have two sliding side menu's. In the centre view, I currently load a single view upon the application starting. That view contains table rows with an onClick event to open up a detailed view of the item clicked.

My question is: how do I open up the detailed window and passing an object to it?

Comment: it will be good if you share some code.

Answer (score 0):

To get round this issue, any item that needed to be addressed in other views/windows was assigned a global variable. The instance was then used to reference.